# PHPのif文の構造について教えていただきたいことがあります。

Tags: php, html

いつもお世話になっております。
Web系超初心者のWeb_beginnerです。

HTMLに埋め込まれたPHPのコードで構造が分からない箇所があります。

```
<td><?php if ($zzData['zipcode']) echo '〒' .$zzData['zipcode'] .' '; echo $zzData['prefecture'] .$zzData['address']; ?></td>
```

それは上記のようなコード（もちろん変数名などは変えています）なのですが・・・

1. if文の構造について 
   上記のコードですが、if文はどのように働いているのでしょうか？「zipcode」があったら「〒zipcode」を表示しないさい、という感じの意味なのでしょうか？
2. `.' ';`について
   if文の途中で`.' ';`と記述があるのですが、これはどういう意味なのでしょうか？
3. `.$`について
   変数名の前に`.$`（ダラーの前にドットが付いている）とありますが、どういった意味で変数の前にドット（.）が付いているのでしょうか？

PHPの本や他のWebサイトにも、記載例や説明がなかったので、こちらのサイトに教わりにきました。

どうぞご教授よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: Shirone様、編集を手伝っていただき、ありがとうございました。私はお礼がしたいのですが、このサイトでお礼をするためにはどのような方法があるのでしょうか？

Comment: もう少し権限が解放されると、自分の評価点から評価をお裾分けできる「お礼」がありますが、お気持ちだけ受け取っておきます。@Web_beginner さんのためだけではなく、以後この投稿を見る人皆のためになるように修正をしています。今後 @Web_beginner さんが、他の方の力になれることがあったら、是非そのときに力を貸してあげてください。ありがとうございます。

Comment: [現在「お礼」と訳されている機能](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)は、賞金を設定して回答を募るものなので少し用途が違う気がします。[ヘルプ記事](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)を参考にするなら、Shironeさんの回答に[投票](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1528/8000)または承認してはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: @unarist さん、ありがとうございます。 お礼…そういう意味でのお礼だったのですね。使ったことが無く勘違いしてました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: @Web_beginner さん：参考までに、他投稿の編集提案にも[信用度+2](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)が設定されています。直接相手に渡す"お礼"とはちょっと違いますが、編集された方にもちゃんとメリットがあります。

Comment: 皆様、アドバイスありがとうございます。それでは、まず「投票」というのを試してみたいと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML の td タグと一緒になっていますが、td タグは今回の説明に必要ないため省きます。
PHP の箇所だけ抜き出し、改行を入れ、ブロックを追加してみると以下のようになります。

```
if ($zzData['zipcode']) {
    echo '〒' .$zzData['zipcode'] .' ';
}
echo $zzData['prefecture'] .$zzData['address'];
```

1. if文の構造について
   これはその通りです。郵便番号があった場合のみ、"〒000-0000" のように郵便番号を表示していると思います。
2. `.' ';` について
   PHP で文字列を連結する際に `.` にて連結できます。
   上述の `.' ';` は、郵便番号の後ろに半角空白を連結しているのでしょうね。
3. `.$`について
   PHP における `$xxxx` ( ダラーから始まる文字 ) は変数を表しますが、それをただ単に `.` で文字列連結しているだけです。

3 の `.$` について仰っている箇所は以下の

> echo $zzData['prefecture'] .$zzData['address'];

2回目の `$zzData` の前にある `.$` だと思いますが、これは "県(prefecture)" と "住所(address)" を文字列連結しています。

具体的な動作として、変数 `$zzData` に郵便番号('zipcode')があれば以下のような出力になります。

`〒000-0000 xxxx県xxxx市...`

変数 `$zzData` に郵便番号が無ければ以下のように出力されます。

`xxxx県xxxx市...`

以上となります。

Comment: 引用の後ろに改行がないので、`$zzDataの前だと思いますが～`も引用になってしまっているようです。 http://qiita.com/Qiita/items/c686397e4a0f4f11683d#blockquotes---%E5%BC%95%E7%94%A8

Comment: @unarist 修正しましたのでご確認ください

Comment: 早速のご回答ありがとうございます。またPHPについて知識が増えました。とても助かります。

Answer (score 3):

1.
その通りです。
http://www.tryphp.net/2011/10/11/phpref-ronrichi/
C言語のIF文に近い感じでしょうか、変数に値がセットされていると
大体のケースはTRUEと判定されます。

2.
PHPで「.」ドットは文字列結合に使います。つまりスペース一文字を結合しています。

3.
2と同様で文字列結合に使っています。

Comment: 早速のご回答ありがとうございます。ドット=文字列結合。しっかりと頭に収めておきます。